# (Java ) Finding the largest number in an array and it's location

Tags: java, arrays, location

I'm currently learning Java and while I'm able to find the largest number I'm stuck on how to find it's location. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Random;
public class FindingLargestValueInAnArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random number = new Random();

        int[] array_1 = new int[10];

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            int randNum = 1 + number.nextInt(99);
            array_1[i] = randNum;
        }

        System.out.print("Array:");

        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array_1[i]);
        }

        int largeNumb = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            if (array_1[i] > largeNumb) {
                largeNumb = array_1[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nThe largest value is 
            "+largeNumb);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get an another variable for the `index = 0` and then put it inside the if statement and make it equal to `index = i;`. After the loop ends the largest value index would be stored here.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class FindingLargestValueInAnArray {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random number = new Random();

        int[] array_1 = new int[10];

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            int randNum = 1 + number.nextInt(99);
            array_1[i] = randNum;
        }

        System.out.print("Array:");

        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array_1[i]);
        }

        int largeNumb = 0;
        int index = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            if (array_1[i] > largeNumb) {
                largeNumb = array_1[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The largest value is " + largeNumb + " and it's location is" + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can make an int index=0
in the loop where you check if the number is bigger in the body of the if make infex=i. This way you will always have both the value and the index of the largest numnber.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class FindingLargestValueInAnArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random number = new Random();

        int[] array_1 = new int[10];

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            int randNum = 1 + number.nextInt(99);
            array_1[i] = randNum;
        }

        System.out.print("Array:");

        for (i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array_1[i]);
        }

        int largeNumb = array_1[0];
        int index = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < array_1.length; i++) {
            if (array_1[i] > largeNumb) {
                largeNumb = array_1[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nThe largest value is :" + largeNumb + " and it's index is: " + index);
      }
}
```